# After install github, errors trying to create a commit

Tags: git, github, terminal

After install github, and trying to set it up for the first time, I type

> git init

and everything's fine. Then I type

> git add .

and again, no errors.

However, when I get to the step

> git commit –m "first"

It results in the following errors

> 1. error: pathspec '–m' did not match any file(s) known to git.
> 2. error: pathspec 'first' did not match any file(s) known to git.

What do I do from here?

Comment: Are you running all of those from the same directory? What does `git status` give you? Also make sure that you are using the right hyphen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rm: cannot remove '–rf': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45592535/rm-cannot-remove-rf-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: are you using a non-standard shell to execute these commands? It's almost like your command line parser is mucking up the argument list it passes to git (ed: or a unexpected character is being passed that the parser interprets unexpectedly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've supplied double '-' characters to the -m argument. Remove one of the dashes and try again. Post the output from `git status` if it does fail again.

EDIT: not sure if it's a double dash or just an overly "helpful" font. Are there any files in the directory to actually commit? What got staged when you entered `git add .`?

EDIT #2: @litelite makes the relevant and definitely likely point that it might be a Unicode dash not a 'regular' dash character in his comment to the OP

Comment: It's not a double dash. Look at the answer (by me) of the dupe I flagged. it's the exact same thing.

Comment: I think you're right on that. I thought something looked funny with the dash!

Comment: I actually answered here and OP seemed to say it solved his problem but my answer got deleted by an admin for being too similar to the dupe  :/